# How can I change eclipse.ini file via p2 repository update to make -vm to look another JRE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We want eclipse.ini to point to another JRE. How can we change our eclipse.ini file  via eclipse update mechanism to make -vm parameter point to another jre.

We want to add a new line -vm and then C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe on the following new line in eclipse.ini via p2 repository update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a p2.inf file to customize the p2 metadata generated for your bundle.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_customizing_metadata.html
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Customizing_Metadata
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Engine/Touchpoint_Instructions

You want touchpoint instructions, the "addProgramArg" and "addJvmArg" add arguments to the eclipse.ini file. (You may also want removeProgramArg and removeJvmArg in the unconfigure or uninstall phase to remove the options when your plugin gets uninstalled or upgraded)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: what is the difference between instructions.configure and instructions.install ?

Comment: `instructions.{phase} = {raw actions}`
`instructions.{phase}.import = {qualified action name} [,{qualified action name}]* (optional)`

Where {phase} is a p2 installation phase (collect, configure, install, uninstall, unconfigure, etc). 
Note:
The {raw actions} will be "appended" to the end of any instructions already being generated.
The qualified action names for the IU's touchpoint type are implicitly imported. All other actions need to be imported.